# Replace dynamic hyperlinks with null in a column using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

One of the columns in my data frame contains some text with hyper links and I want to replace all the hyperlinks with null.

```
df_new["column_name"] = df_new["column_name"].replace(to_replace =r'https://example.com/xyz/pqr/*.html$', value = '', regex = True)
```

Eg: The hyper links will be of the following format:

```
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/xxxxx.html 
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/yyyyy.html
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/zzzzz.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.+` for select all values with one or more repetitions (+), with `\.` for escape `.`, because special regex character (any character):

```
df_new["column_name"]=df_new["column_name"].replace(r'https://example\.com/xyz/pqr/.+\.html$',
                                                      value = '', regex = True)
```

Comment: you missed one 'example\.com'

Comment: @jezrael you beat me again :)

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
import re
df_new["column_name"] = df_new.column_name.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"https:.+html",  value = '', x)
```